# Calling a helper function from inside a class variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Consider the following code:

```py
# foo.py

class A:
    def _foo():
        print('hello world')
    
    bar = {'foo': _foo}

    def run_bar(self):
        self.bar['foo']()

def main():
    A().run_bar()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    raise SystemExit(main())
```

It runs just fine with Python 3.9.5:

```
python3.9 foo.py
> hello world
```

but mypy [will give me](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes&gist=39b4b09c2cb8a01ef7f06d8141b672f6) the following error:

```sh
mypy foo.py
> foo.py:2: error: Method must have at least one argument
> Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Is there a way to tell mypy that this function will only ever get called as a class variable ? If no, is this bad practice? I know I could simply add `# type: ignore`, but that seems too hacky.

Comment: Should be `def _foo(self):`

Comment: You could just define `_foo` outside your class, if it isn't really a class method or instance method.

Comment: i suggest to use staticmethod there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways of doing this:

**1. Use a `staticmethod`**

Either like this:

```
from typing import Callable, Any

class A:
    bar: dict[str, Callable[..., Any]] = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.bar.update({'foo': self._foo})

    @staticmethod
    def _foo():
        print('hello world')

    def run_bar(self):
        self.bar['foo']()
    

def main():
    A().run_bar()
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    raise SystemExit(main())
```

Or like this:

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def _foo():
        print('hello world')
 
    def run_bar(self):
        getattr(self, '_foo')()
        

def main():
    A().run_bar()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    raise SystemExit(main())
```

**2. Put the function outside of the class**

```
def _foo():
    print('hello world')


class A:
    bar = {'foo': _foo}
   
    def run_bar(self):
        self.bar['foo']()
    

def main():
    A().run_bar()
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    raise SystemExit(main())
```